# MediaPipe Preview - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.tasks'

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, mediapipe

I'm trying to use the MediaPipe Solutions Preview to use Object Detection features inside Python.
I'm following this guide https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python but I suppose that I'm actually installing the stable version of MediaPipe by doing "pip install mediapipe" and not the preview one.

When I try to import for example "from mediapipe.tasks import python" or "from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision" I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.tasks'

How can I proceed to actually get the preview version of MediaPipe?
<s>Currently I'm using version 0.9.0.1.</s>
I found out I'm actually installing version 0.8.9.1 which is from 2021, so I suppose that's the issue. I can't seem to be able to install the latest version, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.9 (from versions: 0.8.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.9
```

I tried using `0.9`, `0.9.0` and `0.9.0.1`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    pkg-config \
    libgl1-mesa-glx

# Pre-built CPU-only OpenCV packages for Python with extra modules. When done needing GUI use opencv-contrib-python-headless \
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install numpy && \
    pip install opencv-contrib-python && \
    pip install protobuf==3.20.* && \
    pip install mediapipe

COPY /app /app
```

Comment: What version number of MediaPipe are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the original question, I'm using version 0.9.0.1.

Comment: The python package is shared between legacy Solutions and preview Tasks, so the version of MediaPipe you're using contains the tasks. I am unable to reproduce the issue. For example, with this [code sample](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlesamples/mediapipe/blob/main/examples/object_detection/python/object_detector.ipynb), I am able to import the modules.

Comment: @JenPerson thank You for Your help. I just noticed that pip is installing an older version instead of the latest one, I suppose that's the issue. I've updated the question with more details. Let me know if You have any ideas.